# Starting intent with adb opens complete with dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a simple app for android and it works fine, however when I open an activity with adb the emulator displays a complete with dialogue: Complete action using __.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that because I moved the activity classes to another package, the old package info remained in gradle.build and in the android manifest.

Adb did not say that such an activity does not exist because I had a space in between the package name and activity name and it started some other application apparently.

Answer (score 1):

It's just asking you how you want to run your API. Just select API Demos and "Always". It won't ask you again.